# Eskimo's pia ComboBox component throws exception when calling .selectedItem()

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4.6, flex-mobile

I'm working on a Flex mobile application targeting both iOS and Android.
I'm currently using Eskimo library for different controls, one of them is the  I've been using for a long time across different versions of AIR.

However, I've upgraded my project to run the latest AIR 4.0 so I can go along with the latest news from Apple (you can find a thread talking about that [here](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1378623?tstart=0))

And since then, everytime I'm trying to retrieve the selected item, as following:

```
if (registeredUsersCombo.selectedItem)
{
    // Do something
}
```

I'm getting the following exception (I don't have access to the lines specified in the two first sentences):

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>
> at com.pialabs.eskimo.components::UniqueChoiceList/get selectedItem()[/Users/fred/Projets/eskimo/piaMobileLib/src/main/flex/com/pialabs/eskimo/components/UniqueChoiceList.as:66]
>
> at com.pialabs.eskimo.components::ComboBox/get selectedItem()[/Users/fred/Projets/eskimo/piaMobileLib/src/main/flex/com/pialabs/eskimo/components/ComboBox.as:158]
>
> at aproove.presentation::InvitationPopUp/checkInvitedUserInformation()[C:\Users\XXXX\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\XXXXXXX\src\XXXX\presentation\InvitationPopUp.mxml:168]

Did anyone encountered the same issue? Maybe I could work it around using .getSelectedLabelDisplay() which is still working, but it's really not the cleanest solution in my opinion.

**EDIT**:
I've noticed something interesting. The issue is occurring when I try to get the selectedItem directly from the component ID, as in the following:

```
myCombo.selectedItem // Exception thrown
```

However, if the same ComboBox is reached through an event handler, the selectedItem() is working fine !

```
event.currentTarget.selectedItem; // event.currentTarget being the ComboBox, this is working
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the component does not init completely before you call registeredUsersCombo.selectedItem , Please show more code

Comment: I'm not sure because the exception is thrown at a button click, which is happening some time after the view containing the ComboBox has been loaded.